# function of "to" in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context, to-infinitive

> Why is paper money considered fiat money?
>   A dollar bill contains only about 3 cents worth of paper, printing inks, and other materials. Also, nowhere on paper is there **any promise to redeem it for gold, silver, or anything else.**

I am not sure what the latter half of the sentence means, but I think it means:

"People can't exchange paper money for gold, silver, or anything else."

And I guess **to** here is attached to promise, so it adds information to **promise** , so it should share the same function as relative clause?

If the above understanding is right, can I rephrase the sentence into:

> Nowhere on paper is there any promise which allows user to redeem it for gold, silver, or anything else.

Comment: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/verbs-followed-infinitive

Comment: No: the infinitival clause is complement of "promise".

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for the answer, is my understanding of the meaning the sentence correct?

Comment: Not quite: the infinitival defines what the promise is, rather than expressing some property of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the sentence is correct as is your reasoning!